# Does anyone know how to do textview list like in attached image?

Tags: android, list, textview, outline

Does anyone know how to do textview list like in attached image ?
Children in multiple rows depending on their size.

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, do you want a text view with rounded corners?

Comment: i think you should make a custom view which would accept strings at runtime and use that view as a list item

Comment: Try this: http://textextjs.com/

Comment: There is now an open-source Android FlowLayout available under the BSD license: https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you to arrrange your tags.
[image]
[FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Check below links, it might help you.

1. Use multiple autocompleted textview :Bubble-Text-Library(you can change view from xml file also) [Link](https://github.com/AmaldevTA/Android-Chip-Bubble-Text-Library)
2. android-chips(suggested by @ Suhas Bachewar)  [Link](https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips)
3. chipview(multi custom color) [Link](https://github.com/Plumillon/ChipView)

and many more are there

Answer (score 0):

> Set it as your textView background
>
> Save it in drawable folder

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <gradient
        android:endColor="@color/something"
        android:centerColor="@color/something_else"
        android:startColor="@color/something_else_still"
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners
        android:radius="3dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Not exact, but you can edit it, to match your requirement